# Knockout mapping ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have static method `"objectToMyObject"` for convert object properties to `MyObject` properties  `objectToMyObject`. 
I'm trying change "`objectToMyObject`" to "`mapping.fromJS(data)`". But I can't decidedd that. Hom implement this problem?

```
// My get method:
 getMyObject(url: string, params: any, onSuccess: () = > {}, onError: (message: string) = > {}) {
     this.invokeAjax(url, params, (data) = > {
             if (!data.succeeded) {
                 onError(data.error);
             } else {
                 this.editMyObject(MyObject.objectToMyObject(data));
                 //this.editMyObject(<any>this.editMyObject((<any>ko).mapping.fromJS(data)));
                 onSuccess();
             }
         });
 }



 // My invoke method:
 invokeAjax(url: string, params, callback: (result: any) = > {}) {
     $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'GET',
             data: params,
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,
             success: (data) = > {
                 callback(data);
             },
             error: (data) = > {
                 this.succeeded(false);
             }
         });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code. As you can see it always calls the callback function with a success parameter.

In your code "if(!data.succeeded)" statement will always returns false. If you want to check the "succeeded" value you should write this : "if(!data.succeeded())"

```
// My get method:
 getMyObject(url: string, params: any, onSuccess: () = > {}, onError: (message: string) = > {}) {
     this.invokeAjax(url, params, (data, success) = > {
             if (!success) {
                 onError(data.error);
             } else {
                 ko.mapping.fromJS](vm /*your view model (may be this)*/, {}, data)
                 //this.editMyObject(MyObject.objectToMyObject(data));
                 //this.editMyObject(<any>this.editMyObject((<any>ko).mapping.fromJS(data)));
                 onSuccess();
             }
    });
 }



 // My invoke method:
 invokeAjax(url: string, params, callback: (result: any, success : any) = > {}) {
     $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'GET',
             data: params,
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,
             success: (data) = > {
                 callback(data, true);
             },
             error: (data) = > {
                 callback(data, false);
             }
    });
 }
```

**My response to your first question**

Early, in your code you bound the view model to the view by calling ko.applyBindings(vm).
Now, when you receive the refreshed data from the ajax callback, you can call [ko.mapping.fromJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)(vm, {}, data);

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, Damien. How can I replace "objectToMyObject" with mapping.fromJS. I didn't "objectToMyObject" method

Comment: I modified my post accordingly to your question.

Comment: Thank you, Damien.I trying ko.mapping.fromJS(this, {}, data); but I have error: The property 'mapping' does not exist on value of type 'knockout'. If I trying (<any>ko).mapping.fromJS(this, {}, data); In Chrome console I have new error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined

Comment: It's because the ko.mapping library is missing. You can download it here : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you, Damien. It's work for me with ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm /*your view model (may be this)*/)

Comment: Glad to hear that solves your problem. You sould mark the question as resolved, if it is.